# How to add object as attribute using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I am trying to add object to attribute using javascript but it is passing as object object.

```
var choice = {'name':'one',id:1}
```

COde

```
return '<a href="/users?userId='+
  choice.id+'" class="tool-tip" title="'+
  choice.name+'"><span data-desc="'+
  choice+'">'+this.label(choice)+'</span></a>';
```

it is creating as

```
<a href="/users?userId=1" class="tool-tip" title="userName">
<span data-desc="Object Object"></span></a>
```

Where i am dong wrong?

Comment: Do not use a string to create elements.

Comment: choice is an object, what did you expect? Post `this.label` too

Comment: @epascarello what else i can use?

Comment: @mplungjan its an object, on click of element i have to do some operations

Comment: What is `this.label()`? What do you need to write inside `data-desc` attribute? This are the details that you need to provide if you want a valid answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When manipulating the DOM via Javascript, there is absolutely no need to go through the intermediary simplified HTML representation. Create DOM objects directly with arbitrary properties:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = '/users?userId=' + choice.id;
link.classList.add('tool-tip');
link.title = choice.name;

var content = document.createElement('span');
content.desc = choice;
content.textContent = this.label(choice);

link.appendChild(content);

return link;
```

And then `appendChild` this `link` to some other DOM element…

If you absolutely need `choice` to be part of `dataset` (`data-*="…"`) because some other component depends on it… well, `dataset` can only hold strings, not objects, so you would have to at least agree that the value is a JSON string:

```
link.dataset.desc = JSON.stringify(choice);
```

Comment: `content.dataset.desc = choice` STILL gives `<span data-desc="[object Object]">`

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that `dataset` is a map of strings… Updated. @Kunal